# Jax-ws multiple webservices

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

Originally I was sent one wsdl from a 3rd party and chose jax-ws for the solution. I soon realized that the webservice did not contain all the functions, when I asked about it I was sent 4 more wsdls... One for each function.

Each function has it's own wsdl. For the first phase things are ok as there are only 5 functions, but over the next 3 month we are adding 40 more. Can somebody suggest how I can handle this? I need some way to stop duplicating code. Currently I have 5 blocks of code that looks very similar for setting up the service. I would hate to have to duplicate it 40 times.

To make matters worse, they all share a common xsd, but don't actually use the xsd other than to extend the types to look the same, but have different names in all the wsdls.

Comment: IMO if the 3rd party choose to send a WSDL file for each web service, well, I would suggest your boss/company to change the provider for being **SO bad designers**. Leaving that problem out, maybe if you write the code you're using to consume the WS people here could give you a hand on your design issue.

Comment: does each endpoint have a different target url?  if so, you're pretty much stuck.  talk to the people designing the endpoints and tell them to stop creating a wsdl per operation.

Comment: I agree with you. I almost had a fit when I saw what was happening. Each operation does have a seperate endpoint. To make matters worse, we are stuck with these providers. Tomorrow I'll escalate this to the appropriate people. As far as I understand their system is still under development.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use reflection and generics. I have a base class that can construct a service and connect to a port based on type.

Still, this is not ideal and you really do not want so many wsdls.